# Reading binary data from a child process in Node.js

Tags: process, node.js, binary

When trying to read data in Node.js from an ImageMagick child process, it comes out corrupted.

A simple test case would be the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = 'convert ./test.jpg -';
exec(cmd, {encoding: 'binary', maxBuffer: 5000*1024}, function(error, stdout) {
  fs.writeFileSync('test2.jpg', stdout);
});
```

I would expect that to be the equivalent of the command line `convert ./test.jpg - > test2.jpg` that does write the binary file correctly.

Originally there was a problem with the maxBuffer option being too small and resulting in a truncated file. After increasing that, the file now appears slightly larger than expected and still corrupted.
The data from stdout is required to send over HTTP.

What would be the correct way to read this data from the ImageMagick stdout?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There were two problems with the initial approach.

1. The maxBuffer needs to be high enough to handle the whole response from the child process.
2. Binary encoding needs to be properly set everywhere.

A full working example would be the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = 'convert ./test.jpg -';
exec(cmd, {encoding: 'binary', maxBuffer: 5000*1024}, function(error, stdout) {
  fs.writeFileSync('test2.jpg', stdout, 'binary');
});
```

Another example, sending the data in an HTTP response using the Express web framework, would like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/myfile', function(req, res) {
  var cmd = 'convert ./test.jpg -';
  exec(cmd, {encoding: 'binary', maxBuffer: 5000*1024}, function(error, stdout) {
     res.send(new Buffer(stdout, 'binary'));
  });
});
```

Comment: You should add res.end(), after res.send(...)

Comment: I was thinking that stdout is already a buffer... well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Ah, problem is:

> If timeout is greater than 0, then it
>   will kill the child process if it runs
>   longer than timeout milliseconds. The
>   child process is killed with
>   killSignal (default: 'SIGTERM').
>   maxBuffer specifies the largest amount
>   of data allowed on stdout or stderr -
>   if this value is exceeded then the
>   child process is killed.

Source: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/child_processes.html#child_process.exec

So if your image is over the default buffer size of 200*1024 bytes, your image is going to be corrupted as you mentioned. I was able to get it to work with the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var util = require('util');

var output_file = fs.createWriteStream('test2.jpg', {encoding: 'binary'});

var convert = spawn('convert', ['test.jpg', '-']);
convert.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
 output_file.write(data);
});

convert.on('exit', function(code) {
 output_file.end();
});
```

Here I used spawn to get a streamable stdout, then I used a Writeable Stream to write the data in binary format. Just tested it and was able to open the resulting `test2.jpg` image.

**EDIT**: Yes you can use this to send the result over HTTP. Here's an example of me downsizing an image with convert, then posting the result to the glowfoto API:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var url = require('url');

// Technically the only reason I'm using this
// is to get the XML parsed from the first call
// you probably don't need this, but just in case:
//
// npm install xml2js
var xml = require('xml2js');

var post_url;
var input_filename = 'giant_image.jpg';
var output_filename = 'giant_image2.jpg';

// The general format of a multipart/form-data part looks something like:
// --[boundary]\r\n
// Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldname"\r\n
// \r\n
// field value
function EncodeFieldPart(boundary,name,value) {
    var return_part = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    return_part += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"\r\n\r\n";
    return_part += value + "\r\n";
    return return_part;
}

// Same as EncodeFieldPart except that it adds a filename,
// as well as sets the content type (mime) for the part
function EncodeFilePart(boundary,type,name,filename) {
    var return_part = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    return_part += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"\r\n";
    return_part += "Content-Type: " + type + "\r\n\r\n";
    return return_part;
}

// We could use Transfer-Encoding: Chunked in the headers
// but not every server supports this. Instead we're going
// to build our post data, then create a buffer from it to
// pass to our MakePost() function. This means you'll have
// 2 copies of the post data sitting around
function PreparePost() {
  // Just a random string I copied from a packet sniff of a mozilla post
  // This can be anything you want really
  var boundary = "---------------------------168072824752491622650073";
  var post_data = '';

  post_data += EncodeFieldPart(boundary, 'type', 'file');
  post_data += EncodeFieldPart(boundary, 'thumbnail', '400');
  post_data += EncodeFilePart(boundary, 'image/jpeg', 'image', output_filename);

  fs.readFile(output_filename, 'binary', function(err,data){
    post_data += data;
    // This terminates our multi-part data
    post_data += "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
    // We need to have our network transfer in binary
    // Buffer is a global object
    MakePost(new Buffer(post_data, 'binary'));
  });
}

function MakePost(post_data) {
  var parsed_url = url.parse(post_url);

  var post_options = {
    host: parsed_url.hostname,
    port: '80',
    path: parsed_url.pathname,
    method: 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------168072824752491622650073',
        'Content-Length' : post_data.length
    }
  };

  var post_request = http.request(post_options, function(response){
    response.setEncoding('utf8'); 
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
      console.log(chunk);
    });
  });

  post_request.write(post_data);
  post_request.end();
}

// Glowfoto first makes you get the url of the server
// to upload
function GetServerURL() {
  var response = '';

  var post_options = {
      host: 'www.glowfoto.com',
      port: '80',
      path: '/getserverxml.php'
  };

  var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');

      // Here we buildup the xml
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        response += chunk;
      });

      // When we're done, we parse the xml
      // Could probably just do string manipulation instead,
      // but just to be safe
      res.on('end', function(){
        var parser = new xml.Parser();
        parser.addListener('end', function(result){
      // Grab the uploadform element value and prepare our post
          post_url = result.uploadform;
          PreparePost();
        });

    // This parses an XML string into a JS object
        var xml_object = parser.parseString(response);
      });
  });
  post_req.end();

}

// We use spawn here to get a streaming stdout
// This will use imagemagick to downsize the full image to 30%
var convert = spawn('convert', ['-resize', '30%', input_filename, '-']);

// Create a binary write stream for the resulting file
var output_file = fs.createWriteStream(output_filename, {encoding: 'binary'});

// This just writes to the file and builds the data
convert.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  output_file.write(data);
});

// When the process is done, we close off the file stream
// Then trigger off our POST code
convert.on('exit', function(code){
  output_file.end();
  GetServerURL();
});
```

Sample result:

```
$ node test.js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<upload>
<thumburl>http://img4.glowfoto.com/images/2011/05/29-0939312591T.jpg</thumburl>
<imageurl>http://www.glowfoto.com/static_image/29-093931L/2591/jpg/05/2011/img4/glowfoto</imageurl>
<codes>http://www.glowfoto.com/getcode.php?srv=img4&amp;img=29-093931L&amp;t=jpg&amp;rand=2591&amp;m=05&amp;y=2011</codes>
</upload>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's true I completely missed the maxBuffer option, but it doesn't seem to resolve the corruption. If you enlarge that with my example the resulting file is no longer too small but still corrupted. Your example works but I actually need to do more with the data than pipe it straight to another file. More specifically, I would need to write it out in an HTTP response using the express framework for example.

Comment: @Daniel I just tried it by changing the spawn line to : `var convert = spawn('convert', ['test.jpg', '-resize', '50%', '-']);` and got a working JPEG file scaled down 50%. Try updating your post with what you have right now.

Comment: Your example does work. What I meant is that the issue in my example is more than just the maxBuffer. When you increase it, it doesn't resolve the corruption. Unfortunately I can't use your approach as I need to send the file over HTTP so I can't use the fs.createWriteStream. I'm updating the example to correct the maxBuffer.

Comment: @Daniel You can. I just added a proof of concept

Comment: Wow, thanks that's a monster of an example, but I was trying to avoid having to write to a local file. Otherwise using stdout wasn't very useful as the commandline could write to a file without unnecessarily going via node.js. It turns out the problem was maxBuffer as you suggested and not always encoding in binary.

Answer (score 4):

You can also take advantage of io pipes in nodejs

```
var file = fs.createWritableStream("path-to-file", {encoding: 'binary'});
converter = spawn(cmd, ['parameters ommited']);
converter.stdout.pipe(file); //this will set out stdout.write cal to you file
converter.on('exit', function(){ file.end();});
```