# PhantomJS: exported PDF to stdout

Tags: pdf, pipe, file-descriptor, phantomjs, io-redirection

Is there a way to trigger the PDF export feature in PhantomJS without specifying an output file with the .pdf extension? We'd like to use `stdout` to output the PDF.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As pointed out by Niko you can use `renderBase64()` to render the web page to an image buffer and return the result as a base64-encoded string.
But for now this will only work for PNG, JPEG and GIF.

To write something from a phantomjs script to stdout just use the filesystem API.

I use something like this for images :

```
var base64image = page.renderBase64('PNG');
var fs = require("fs");
fs.write("/dev/stdout", base64image, "w");
```

I don't know if the PDF format for `renderBase64()` will be in a future version of phanthomjs but as a workaround something along these lines may work for you:

```
page.render(output);
var fs = require("fs");
var pdf = fs.read(output);
fs.write("/dev/stdout", pdf, "w");
fs.remove(output);
```

Where `output` is the path to the pdf file.

Comment: In order to get this method to work, I had to change the `fs.read` line to `var pdf = fs.open(output, 'rb').read();` -- reading the file in binary form was important (otherwise redirecting stdout to a file led to an incorrect PDF). However I was later able to get this to work with *no temporary file* at all - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17282463/137067

Answer (score 20):

You can output directly to stdout without a need for a temporary file.

`page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: 'pdf' });`

See [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/386) for history on when this was added.

If you want to get HTML from stdin and output the PDF to stdout, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17286691/137067)

Comment: Works nicely, but if you are reading stdout in Node such as described here https://www.npmjs.org/package/phantomjs you need to set the execFile options for binary and probably increase the buffer size as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6170723/2297380

Comment: Here's [documentation from the PhantomJS wiki](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#webpage-render). But for me this method does not respect `page.viewportSize` settings.

Comment: For some reason it works on Mac OS X, but it doesn't work on linux (PhantomJS version 1.9.8).

Comment: even adding the options: {encoding: 'binary', maxBuffer: 5000*1024} this does not arrive to the stdout in node

Comment: For me did not work in windows 7 and phantomjs-prebuilt 2.1.13

Answer (score 19):

Sorry for the extremely long answer; I have a feeling that I'll need to refer to this method several dozen times in my life, so I'll write "one answer to rule them all". I'll first babble a little about files, file descriptors, (named) pipes, and output redirection, and then answer your question.

---

Consider this simple C99 program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s file_name\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "w");
  if (!file) {
    printf("No such file: %s\n", argv[1]);
    return 2;
  }

  fprintf(file, "some text...");

  fclose(file); 

  return 0;
}
```

Very straightforward. It takes an argument (a file name) and prints some text into it. Couldn't be any simpler.

---

Compile it with `clang write_to_file.c -o write_to_file.o` or `gcc write_to_file.c -o write_to_file.o`.

Now, run `./write_to_file.o some_file` (which prints into `some_file`). Then run `cat some_file`. The result, as expected, is `some text...`

Now let's get more fancy. Type `(./write_to_file.o /dev/stdout) > some_file` in the terminal. We're asking the program to write to its *standard output* (instead of a regular file), and then we're redirecting that `stdout` to `some_file` (using `> some_file`). We could've used any of the following to achieve this:

- `(./write_to_file.o /dev/stdout) > some_file`, which means "use `stdout`"
- `(./write_to_file.o /dev/stderr) 2> some_file`, which means "use `stderr`, and redirect it using `2>`"
- `(./write_to_file.o /dev/fd/2) 2> some_file`, which is the same as above; `stderr` is the third file descriptor assigned to Unix processes by default (after `stdin` and `stdout`)
- `(./write_to_file.o /dev/fd/5) 5> some_file`, which means "use your sixth file descriptor, and redirect it to `some_file`"

In case it's not clear, we're using a Unix pipe instead of an actual file (everything is a file in Unix after all). We can do all sort of fancy things with this pipe: write it to a file, or write it to a named pipe and share it between different processes.

---

Now, let's create a named pipe:

```
mkfifo my_pipe
```

If you type `ls -l` now, you'll see:

```
total 32
prw-r--r--  1 pooriaazimi  staff     0 Jul 15 09:12 my_pipe
-rw-r--r--  1 pooriaazimi  staff   336 Jul 15 08:29 write_to_file.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pooriaazimi  staff  8832 Jul 15 08:34 write_to_file.o
```

Note the **p** at the beginning of second line. It means that `my_pipe` is a (named) pipe.

Now, let's specify what we want to do with our pipe:

```
gzip -c < my_pipe > out.gz &
```

It means: `gzip` what I put inside `my_pipe` and write the results in `out.gz`. The `&` at the end asks the shell to run this command in the background. You'll get something like `[1] 10449` and the control gets back to the terminal.

Then, simply redirect the output of our C program to this pipe:

```
(./write_to_file.o /dev/fd/5) 5> my_pipe
```

Or

```
./write_to_file.o my_pipe
```

You'll get

```
[1]+  Done                    gzip -c < my_pipe > out.gz
```

which means the `gzip` command has finished.

Now, do another `ls -l`:

```
total 40
prw-r--r--  1 pooriaazimi  staff     0 Jul 15 09:14 my_pipe
-rw-r--r--  1 pooriaazimi  staff    32 Jul 15 09:14 out.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 pooriaazimi  staff   336 Jul 15 08:29 write_to_file.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pooriaazimi  staff  8832 Jul 15 08:34 write_to_file.o
```

We've successfully `gzip`ed our text!

Execute `gzip -d out.gz` to decompress this `gzip`ed file. It will be deleted and a new file (`out`) will be created. `cat out` gets us:

```
some text...
```

which is what we expected.

*Don't forget to remove the pipe with `rm my_pipe`!*

---

Now back to PhantomJS.

This is a simple PhantomJS script (`render.coffee`, written in CoffeeScript) that takes two arguments: a URL and a file name. It loads the URL, renders it and writes it to the given file name:

```coffee
system = require 'system'

renderUrlToFile = (url, file, callback) ->
  page = require('webpage').create()
  page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height : 800 }
  page.settings.userAgent = 'Phantom.js bot'

  page.open url, (status) ->
    if status isnt 'success'
      console.log "Unable to render '#{url}'"
    else
      page.render file

    delete page
    callback url, file


url         = system.args[1]
file_name   = system.args[2]

console.log "Will render to #{file_name}"
renderUrlToFile "http://#{url}", file_name, (url, file) ->
  console.log "Rendered '#{url}' to '#{file}'"
  phantom.exit()
```

Now type `phantomjs render.coffee news.ycombinator.com hn.png` in the terminal to render Hacker News front page into file `hn.png`. It works as expected. So does `phantomjs render.coffee news.ycombinator.com hn.pdf`.

Let's repeat what we did earlier with our C program:

```
(phantomjs render.coffee news.ycombinator.com /dev/fd/5) 5> hn.pdf
```

It doesn't work... :( Why? Because, as stated on [PhantomJS's manual](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface):

> **render(fileName)**
>
> Renders the web page to an image buffer and save it
>   as the specified file.
>
> Currently the output format is automatically set based on the file
>   extension. Supported formats are PNG, JPEG, and PDF.

It fails, simply because neither `/dev/fd/2` nor `/dev/stdout` end in `.PNG`, etc.

But no fear, named pipes can help you!

Create another named pipe, but this time use the extension `.pdf`:

```
mkfifo my_pipe.pdf
```

Now, tell it to simply `cat` its inout to `hn.pdf`:

```
cat < my_pipe.pdf > hn.pdf &
```

Then run:

```
phantomjs render.coffee news.ycombinator.com my_pipe.pdf
```

And behold the beautiful `hn.pdf`!

Obviously you want to do something more sophisticated that just `cat`ing the output, but I'm sure it's clear now what you should do :)

---

### **TL;DR:**

1. Create a named pipe, using ".pdf" file extension (so it fools PhantomJS to think it's a PDF file):

   ```
   mkfifo my_pipe.pdf
   ```
2. Do whatever you want to do with the contents of the file, like:

   ```
   cat < my_pipe.pdf > hn.pdf
   ```

   which simply `cat`s it to `hn.pdf`
3. In PhantomJS, render to this file/pipe.
4. Later on, you should remove the pipe:

   ```
   rm my_pipe.pdf
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it would address your problem, but you may also check the new `renderBase64()` method added to PhantomJS 1.6: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/webpage.cpp#L623

Unfortunately, the feature is not documented on the wiki yet :/