# PhantomJS: pipe input

Tags: linux, pipe, named-pipes, phantomjs, mkfifo

I am trying to use PhantomJS to render an html page to pdf. 
I do not want to write the files to disk, I have the html in memory, and I want the pdf in memory.

Using the excellent answer from Pooria Azimi at [this question](/questions/11408332/phantomjs-exported-pdf-to-stdout/11489631#11489631), i am able to get the pdf from a named pipe. When trying the same  on the other end (replacing the input file with a named pipe), I end up with a blank pdf.

This is what I am doing now (simplified):

```
mkfifo in_pipe.html out_pipe.pdf
./phantomjs rasterize.js in_pipe.html out_pipe.pdf
```

Then in another terminal:

```
echo '<center>hey!</center>' > in_pipe.html
cat out_pipe.pdf > out.pdf
```

The file out.pdf is created, but is blank. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do what you're looking for very simply (it's just not really documented) directly in PhantomJS.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    fs = require('fs');

page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
page.paperSize = { format: 'Letter', orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };

page.content = fs.read('/dev/stdin');

window.setTimeout(function() {
    page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: 'pdf' });
    phantom.exit();
}, 1);
```

(May need to increase the timeout if you have images that need loading, etc.)

HTML comes in stdin, PDF binary goes out stdout. You can test it like:

`echo "<b>test</b>" | phantomjs makepdf.js > test.pdf && open test.pdf`

Comment: This is actually something I already tried, and found that it didn't work. However, after downloading the newest version, it does indeed work. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using setTimeout would it not be better to use the "load" event? That way you know everything has loaded.