# phantomjs pdf to stdout

Tags: javascript, pdf, stdout, phantomjs

I am desperately trying to output a PDF generated by phantomJS to stdout like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403817/phantomjs-pipe-input/17286691#17286691)

What I am getting is an empty PDF file, although it is not 0 in size, it displays a blank page.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
address;

address = system.args[1];
page.paperSize = {format: 'A4'};

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: 'pdf' });
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

And I call it like so: `phantomjs rasterize.js http://google.com>test.pdf`

I tried changing `/dev/stdout` to `system.stdout` but not luck. Writing PDF straight to file works without any problems.

I am looking for a cross-platform implementation, so I hope this is achievable on non-linux systems.

Comment: what version of phantomjs? try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue on 1.9.2 Win8x64. Not piping the output seems to have some pdf content in the console, but piping the output directly to file via phantomjs rasterize.js > test.pdf has nothing going.

Comment: @philfreo I used 1.9.2 on Win7

Comment: Could you upload somewhere a generated pdf file, it might be worth looking into whether there is some visual issue with the pdf's generated code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When writing output to `/dev/stdout/` or `/dev/stderr/` on Windows, `PhantomJS` goes through the following steps (as seen in the `render` method in [\phantomjs\src\webpage.cpp](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/webpage.cpp)):

1. In absence of `/dev/stdout/` and `/dev/stderr/` a temporary file path is allocated.
2. Call `renderPdf` with the temporary file path.
3. Render the web page to this file path.
4. Read the contents of this file into a `QByteArray`.
5. Call `QString::fromAscii` on the byte array and write to `stdout` or `stderr`.
6. Delete the temporary file.

To begin with, I built the source for `PhantomJS`, but commented out the file deletion. On the next run, I was able to examine the temporary file it had rendered, which turned out to be completely fine. I also tried running `phantomjs.exe rasterize.js http://google.com > test.png` with the same results. This immediately ruled out a rendering issue, or anything specifically to do with PDFs, meaning that the problem had to be related to the way data is written to `stdout`.

By this stage I had suspicions about whether there was some text encoding shenanigans going on. From previous runs, I had both a valid and invalid version of the same file (a PNG in this case).

Using some C# code, I ran the following experiment:

```
//Read the contents of the known good file.
byte[] bytesFromGoodFile = File.ReadAllBytes("valid_file.png");
//Read the contents of the known bad file.
byte[] bytesFromBadFile = File.ReadAllBytes("invalid_file.png");

//Take the bytes from the valid file and convert to a string
//using the Latin-1 encoding.
string iso88591String = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bytesFromGoodFile);
//Take the Latin-1 encoded string and retrieve its bytes using the UTF-8 encoding.
byte[] bytesFromIso88591String = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iso88591String);

//If the bytes from the Latin-1 string are all the same as the ones from the
//known bad file, we have an encoding problem.
Debug.Assert(bytesFromBadFile
    .Select((b, i) => b == bytesFromIso88591String[i])
    .All(c => c));
```

Note that I used ISO-8859-1 encoding as `QT` uses this as the [default encoding for c-strings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#codecForCStrings). As it turned out, all those bytes were the same. The point of that exercise was to see if I could mimic the encoding steps that caused valid data to become invalid.

For further evidence, I investigated [\phantomjs\src\system.cpp](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/system.cpp) and [\phantomjs\src\filesystem.cpp](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/filesystem.cpp).

- In `system.cpp`, the `System` class holds references to, among other things, `File` objects for `stdout`, `stdin` and `stderr`, which are set up to use `UTF-8` encoding.
- When writing to `stdout`, the `write` function of the `File` object is called. This function supports writing to both text and binary files, but because of the way the `System` class initializes them, all writing will be treated as though it were going to a text file.

So the problem boils down to this: we need to be performing a binary write to `stdout`, yet our writes end up being treated as text and having an encoding applied to them that causes the resulting file to be invalid.

---

Given the problem described above, I can't see any way to get this working the way you want on Windows without making changes to the `PhantomJS` code. So here they are:

This first change will provide a function we can call on `File` objects to explicitly perform a binary write.

Add the following function prototype in `\phantomjs\src\filesystem.h`:

```
bool binaryWrite(const QString &data);
```

And place its definition in `\phantomjs\src\filesystem.cpp` (the code for this method comes from the `write` method in this file):

```
bool File::binaryWrite(const QString &data)
{
    if ( !m_file->isWritable() ) {
        qDebug() << "File::write - " << "Couldn't write:" << m_file->fileName();
        return true;
    }

    QByteArray bytes(data.size(), Qt::Uninitialized);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        bytes[i] = data.at(i).toAscii();
    }
    return m_file->write(bytes);
}
```

At around line 920 of `\phantomjs\src\webpage.cpp` you'll see a block of code that looks like this:

```
    if( fileName == STDOUT_FILENAME ){
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), O_BINARY);            
#endif      

        ((File *)system->_stderr())->write(QString::fromAscii(name.constData(), name.size()));

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), O_TEXT);
#endif          
    }
```

Change it to this:

```
   if( fileName == STDOUT_FILENAME ){
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), O_BINARY);
        ((File *)system->_stdout())->binaryWrite(QString::fromAscii(ba.constData(), ba.size()));
#elif            
        ((File *)system->_stderr())->write(QString::fromAscii(name.constData(), name.size()));
#endif      

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), O_TEXT);
#endif          
    }
```

So what that code replacement does is calls our new `binaryWrite` function, but does so guarded by a `#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32` block. I did it this way so as to preserve the old functionality on non-Windows systems which don't seem to exhibit this problem (or do they?). Note that this fix only applies to writing to `stdout` - if you want to you could always apply it to `stderr` but it may not matter quite so much in that case.

In case you just want a pre-built binary (who wouldn't?), you can find `phantomjs.exe` with these fixes on my [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7B74353C7AA90815!116&authkey=!AEoocwDfgMkI6oI&ithint=file,.exe). My version is around 19MB whereas the one I downloaded earlier was only about 6MB, though I followed the instructions [here](http://phantomjs.org/build.html), so it should be fine.

Comment: This is amazing, thanks so much for your help, time and effort put into this answer!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's right ISO-8859-1 is the default encoding for QT so you will need to add the required parameter to the command line --output-encoding=ISO-8859-1 so the pdf output won't be corrupted

i.e.

phantomjs.exe rasterize.js --output-encoding=ISO-8859-1 < input.html > output.pdf

and rasterize.js looks like this (tested, works for both Unix and Windows)

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system');

page.viewportSize = {width: 600, height: 600};
page.paperSize = {format: 'A4', orientation: system.args[1], margin: '1cm'};

page.content = system.stdin.read();

window.setTimeout(function () {
    try {
        page.render('/dev/stdout', {format: 'pdf'});
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message + ';;' + output_file);
    }
    phantom.exit();
}, 1000);
```

or alternatively you can set encoding using stdout and if you are reading from UTF-8 stream then you might have to set encoding for stdin as well;

```
system.stdout.setEncoding('ISO-8859-1');
system.stdin.setEncoding('UTF-8');
page.content = system.stdin.read();
```

Comment: Thanks man, crazy how such an old question received a new answer, thanks for your time! I wasn't working on that project for a while, but will revisit it some time soon.

Comment: `system.stdout.setEncoding('ISO-8859-1');` <-- this line saved me after hours of debugging. Thank you so much for this answer!!

Comment: @Khan No worries :)

Comment: Wow. This also turned out to be key for rendering the PDF output to /dev/stdout in a C# MVC application using the NReco.PhantomJS wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to output the pdf to stdout? Couldn't you change the code to:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
address;

address = system.args[1];
output  = system.args[2];
page.paperSize = {format: 'A4'};

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output, { format: 'pdf' });
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

and use it like this:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://google.com test.pdf
```

Comment: That's what I was doing as a work around, but my idea was to create pdf's on the fly. Pushing data abck and forth between node-webkit push and phantomjs.

Comment: I'll give a deep look so, probably there is some character that is messing up the PDF structure.