# slimerjs - open webpage that is passed via stdin?

Tags: phantomjs, slimerjs

Can slimerjs take a webpage as input via stdin?

E.g. generateHtmlFileAndWriteToStdOut | slimerjs

I want to use slimerjs in a script pipeline.

Comment: Probably not considering that they added stdout support in the newest version 0.9.6.

Comment: For the curious (and for people like me who misunderstood your question on first read, and went to post an answer involving `xargs`!) here is an example of how to do it in PhantomJS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17286691/841830  (that also shows how to render a pdf to stdout)

Answer (score 1):

The present version does not support stdin.

When version 1.0 is released, the product will have api parity with phantom js and support stdin.